# Find and replace regex for visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I have a **lot** of strings like this to find and replace in visual studio:

```
$CLICKTHRU:Dark-Shadows-Reunion-Experience$
$CLICKTHRU:Pirahna-3DD-Experience$
$CLICKTHRU:The-Dictator$
```

I've been trying to follow the instructions on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but I have got a little stuck.

Here's my shameful attempt so far:

```
\$CLICKTHRU\:[:a|-|\$]
```

Tested on the first string that only matches

```
$CLICKTHRU:D
```

Could  anyone give me a hand with a brief explanation?

Comment: What are you trying to replace them with? What should the result for each one look like?

Comment: @Ahmad Mageed: Just empty space. They are click-through prefixes on urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern: `\$CLICKTHRU\:[^$]+\$`

The `$` is a metacharacter so it must be escaped to be interpreted literally, except when it occurs within a character class. In Visual Studio the colon has to be escaped as well.

- `\$CLICKTHRU\:` pretty straightforward given the above explanation. This is mostly matching literal characters.
- `[^$]+` is a negative character class, since it starts with a `^` inside the square brackets. It matches any character that is not a `$` character. The `+` indicates that the pattern should be matched one or more times.
- `\$` match the ending `$` character.

Comment: That's absolutely outstanding. You've just saved hours of work! 474 instances in one document alone.